# Java JPanel mouse listener doesn't work over its components

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

What is the solution to this problem?

I added a mouse listener to a JPanel, but that panel is full of buttons which cover the entire area of the JPanel.

Example (pseudo) code:

```
Create JPanel
Set to GridLayout
Add 25 buttons (5x5 grid)
Add MouseListener to JPanel
```

MouseListener/MouseMotionListener:

```
onMouseMove { print out X,Y co-ords of mouse }
```

The co-ords are never printed out until I get right to the edge of the JPanel container, because the buttons are blocking the rest of it.

How can I make the mouse listener work over all of the panel's components without having to add the listener to each component - Or am I supposed to add the listener to each component?

**ADDED INFO:**
I'm trying to add a touch-gesture for a touch-screen system (swiping the panel causes an action to occur).
I'm pretty confident about recognising the gesture myself, but I was really looking for a 'better' way than to add a copy of the listener to each component (this would be even worse for me, because the components are changing).

I am going to try to add it to the glassPane instead... (at the moment getRootPane() gives me NullPointerException)

**EDIT:**
I now know that I'm trying to getRootPane() from a JPanel which is not the root container, thats why i'm getting a `null`. I need to do this on the main JFrame.

**EDIT2:**
Okay so I've done that (added glass pane to main JFrame), at first I had a problem because I didn't do this:

`myGlassPane.setVisible(true);`

So it seemed like it wasn't working. But once I did that all I had to do was set the opaque flag to false to make it transparent

`myGlassPane.setOpaque(false);`

So now i'm getting the X,Y co-ords printed out over the buttons and everything, however the buttons aren't working because there's a panel over them.

Comment: You may have to use the glasspane to intercept the mouse and then have it dispatch the mouse events to all underlying components below.

Comment: Don't use a `MouseListener` for buttons!  An `ActionListener` will respond to both mouse & keyboard input.

Comment: Hi pete :D. I can't get around the `NullPointerException` when I try `myPanel.getRootPane()...` when I'm trying to get to the glassPane.

Comment: Hi andrew, its not -for- the buttons, its for the window (which at the moment is holding buttons). I'm actually trying to add a touch-gesture (when a backward-swipe is made the previous panel will be shown again)

Comment: Make sure to prefix comments with @PersonID to ensure they are notified.

Comment: *"a backward-swipe"* Works well for touch phones, but is hardly the 'path of least surprise' for a desktop GUI.  :(

Comment: @418556 It's actually for a touch-screen system, which will never have a non-touch monitor. Sorry if I didn't include enough info in the first place

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"@418556 got it :)"* By 'PersonId' I did mean like at the start of this comment!

Comment: @AndrewThompson ohh I got it now. Sorry

Comment: Success!  I was notified of that one.  (applause..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace JButton with a custom button.  Forward the events you need from the button to the button's parent.  Here is an example that will forward the mouse entered event.  Adjust forwarding and add exception/error handling as necessary.

```
class JJButton extends JButton {
    {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            if (JJButton.this.getParent()!=null){
                MouseListener[] ml = JJButton.this.getParent().getMouseListeners();
                for (MouseListener l : ml) {
                    l.mouseEntered(e);
                }
            }
        }
        });
    }
    public JJButton(String string) {
        super(string);
    }    
}
```

Comment: This would've been what I would have done, had I not finally got my events working through the glass pane, so i'm accepting this as the answer to this question. Thanks.

Comment: This is what I have done now - after finding out the long/hard way that I have no way of making my Java application allow MouseListener events to work with more than 1 layer. Thanks again @ChuckFricano.

Answer (score 2):

Add your listener to both your panel and rhe buttons.

Comment: So is that normal convention @Snicolas ?

Comment: Not at all, but what you 're lookin' for is not normal convention neither. :)

Comment: But be confident that sharing listeners can be a common practice. Maybe more sharing actions though. Anyway, much better than deduplicatnig code.